# Creating TTL indexes with MongoDB and Prisma

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, prisma

I am trying to create a Token collection that store validation tokens that will expire at a particular time. I want that document to automatically get deleted when that happens. From my research, there is something called TTL(time to live) in MongoDB which will run a background process to delete expired documents. Mongoose supports this as well.

Is there any support or workaround for this scenario in Prisma?

Comment: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5430